# How to Focus Two Text Boxes as SelectedItemChanged event of Treeview is triggerd?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, focus

I am trying to focus the two text boxes as the user selects the treeview item in treeview. I am using a SlectedItemChanged event to achieve this. I need to focus both the text boxes at the same time.

```
    delegate void voiDelegate();
    private void click(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        TreeViewItem t;
        t =(TreeViewItem) tvMain.SelectedItem;
        StackPanel s = (StackPanel)t.Header;
        List<TextBlock> l = new List<TextBlock>(3);
        foreach (TextBlock children in s.Children)
        {
            l.Add(children);
        }
        string ch = l[3].Text;
        string[] sp = ch.Split('-');
        int te = Convert.ToByte(sp[1]) - Convert.ToByte(sp[0]) + 1;
        PacketDisplay1.SelectionStart = PacketDisplay2.SelectionStart = Convert.ToByte(sp[0]);
        PacketDisplay1.SelectionLength= PacketDisplay2.SelectionLength = te;
        voiDelegate giveFocusDelegate = new voiDelegate(giveFocus);
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(giveFocusDelegate, new object[] { });

    }
    private void giveFocus()
    {
        PacketDisplay1.Focus();
        PacketDisplay2.Focus();
    }
```

Here focus is happening only in PacketDisplay2 text box.
 how can I achieve Focus in Both text boxes?
 thanks.

Comment: Why focus on both?, are you trying to input same value in both of them?

Comment: I am developing a sniffer in that I need to focus on a Text (i.e Bytes) as user clicks on the treeview item

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to give focus to 2 textboxes at the same time.
The moment you call PacketDisplay2.Focus(), the PacketDisplay1 control will lose focus.
This is by design of windows.

Read following link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

It says clearly : `Keyboard focus refers to the element that is currently receiving keyboard input. There can be only one element on the whole desktop that has keyboard focus.`

Comment: How can I achieve my requirement, is there any other possibility, otherthan focus() ?

Comment: If your requirement is to give focus to 2 textboxes then that is simply impossible. Or you have to express your requirement by different wording. What is it you are trying to accomplish. For instance if 2 textboxes would have focus and I type text, what would happen ? Keeping 2 textboxes in sync is possible by using binding. But only one textbox can have focus.